# Dependent Function Using Angular Forms with Async Data

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-reactive-forms

The function below needs the values of some `user` properties.  Parameter `scores` is dependent on `user` and is provided by `this.form.get('scores').valueChanges.subscribe((value)`.  The `console.log` correctly shows `scores` as an array and `this.user` as an Observable.

How do I access the property values of `user` needed to return a value.

[Full StackBlitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/using-angular-forms-with-async-data-qzxpxr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fuser.service.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts).  When I change a value of scores, I want stp => Score to Post1 to contain new values.

Thanks to Cory Rylan for the template.

```
  ESA(scores) {
    let stp = [];
    console.log('ESA', scores, this.user);
    scores.map((item: number, index) => {
      stp[index] = this.user.pipe(
        tap((user) => user.scores[index] + 100)
      );
      console.log('stp', stp, item, this.user);
    });
    return stp;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

No idea what you trying to achieve but `this.user.pipe(...)` will not produce any data until you subscribe to it. So i'd recommend either define `user` in the service as `BehaviorSubject<User>` and get it's value by `this.userService.user.getValue()` or subscribe to `userService.loadUser()` in component and update local variable in subscription.

```
constructor(...) {
  this.userService.loadUser().subscribe(user => this.user = user);
...
}
```

Comment: I subscribe with the async pipe in the html.  The stackblitz link shows the form that I am trying to update when a value changes.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Dimanoid, I had to subscribe to the `this.user` -- once as a side effect and once in the html using the `async pipe`.  A revised [StackBlitz is here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/using-angular-forms-with-async-data-yf1daj?file=README.md,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

Data are obtained through a service and provided to the form.  `shareReplay` allows for multiple subscriptions to `this.user`.

```
 this.user = this.userService.loadUser().pipe(
      tap((user) => this.form.patchValue(user)),
      shareReplay()
    );
```

`this.user` is subscribed to in function `userProp()` and property fields are accessed.

```
userProp() {
    let parsArray = [];
    let hCapsArray = [];
    let ci
    this.user.subscribe((user) => {
      parsArray = user.pars;
      hCapsArray = user.hCaps;
      ci = user.ci;
    });
    return [parsArray, hCapsArray, ci] as const;
  }
```

Finally the ESA function is called.  It takes an array of scores and returns adjustments to those scores.

```
 ESA(value) {
    const data = this.userProp(); //First Subcription to User
    const pars = data[0];
    const hCaps = data[1];
    const ci = data[2];
    const value1 = [];
    value
      .forEach((x, index) =>
        x - pars[index] > 3
          ? (value1[index] = pars[index] + 3)
          : x - pars[index] > 2 && hCaps[index] >= ci
          ? (value1[index] = pars[index] + 2)
          : (value1[index] = x)
      );
    console.log('values', value1, value, pars, ci);
    return value1;
  }
```

Comments in the code ask two questions.  First, should I unsubscribe from `this.user`?  Does the `async pipe and shareReplay` automatically unsubscribe all `this.user` subscriptions?  Second, can I use .map instead of the for loop in `loadScoreControls(item)`